# Regex rewrite input string in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a input query string which I want to rewrite into below format.

input :

```
select sum(spend) from test where time = date_add('2008-12-31', 1) and product_name = 'test123';
```

rewritten :

```
select sum(spend) from test where time = date_add('2008-12-31', interval 1 day) and product_name = 'test123';
```

I want to rewrite "date_add('2008-12-31', 1)" with "date_add('2008-12-31', interval 1 day)"

Please advice how can I do it in Java.

Comment: `String myNewString = "select sum(spend) from test where time = date_add('2008-12-31', interval 1 day) and product_name = 'test123';";`

Comment: This regex `\(.*,\s*([0-9]+)\)` would match the number in between `()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final String query = "select sum(spend) from test where time = date_add('2008-12-31', 1) and product_name = 'test123'";
final String newQuery = query.replaceAll("date_add\\((.*),\\s*([0-9]+)\\)", "date_add($1, interval $2 day)");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mySql.replaceAll("date_add\\(('[^']*'), (\\d+)\\)", "date_add($1, interval $2 day")
```

will do a halfway reasonable job.  It's overly sensitive to white-space positioning, and assumes a literal date string, and will be dodgy if there are string literals containing SQL in your SQL, but it should get you started.

Rewriting source code with regexs is error-prone, so make sure to check the diff of any changes it makes before committing.